# Pesquisa com intervalo de datas

Tags: php, mysql, sql, mysqli

No MySQL possuo uma tabela que tem dois campos do tipo DATE: `data_inicial` e `data_final`.

No Sistema possuo um Campo (TextField) onde digito uma data.

Esta data não precisa ser precisa, mais que corresponda ao intervalo.

Exemplo:

> Valor do Campo: 2015-10-05

Valores na Tabela:

> Data_Inicial   |   Data_Final:
>   2014-12-18           2015-12-18
>   2015-12-19           2016-12-19

Meu SQL:

```
SELECT Id, data_inicial, data_final, valor FROM periodos WHERE PasseioId = 1 and (data_inicial >= 2015-10-14 and data_final <= 2015-10-14)
```

Answer (score 0):

Utilizando [between](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/date-and-time-type-conversion.html):

```
SELECT Id, data_inicial, data_final, valor 
FROM periodos 
WHERE PasseioId = 1 
AND (data_inicial BETWEEN '2014-12-18' AND '2015-12-18')
```

Comment: Pesquisa vem vazia

Comment: Você efetuou a pesquisa utilizando o exemplo no formato datetime? Tentou utilizando somente date? Formatei a resposta

Answer (score 0):

Adicione aspas `'` nas datas `data_inicial >= '2015-10-14' and data_final <= '2015-10-14'`

Comment: Ele só traz a linha dois. mais não confere, pois a data-inicial da linha dois é 2015-12-19 e minha pesquisa é 2015-10-14.